# Simplify the expression $\varphi(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\alpha_i Q(x+\lambda_i)$

Tags: polynomials

> Let the polynomial $ ()$ $-$th degree with real coefficients
> and set real numbers $\lambda_1 <\lambda_2 <... <\lambda_{+1}.$ Simplify the expression
> $$\varphi(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\alpha_i Q(x+\lambda_i),$$
> where $$\alpha_i=\prod_{j=1,j\not=i}^{n+1}\left(\lambda_i-\lambda_j\right), 1\le i \le n+1.$$

#### My work so far:

I used [Lagrange Interpolating Polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInterpolatingPolynomial.html), but I can not bring a solution to the end

Comment: Can you clarify what the $\alpha_i$'s are?  Which one of these holds: $$\alpha_i=\prod_{j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n+1\}\setminus\{i\}}\,\left(\lambda_i-\lambda_j\right)$$ or $$\alpha_i=\prod_{j=i+1}^{n+1}\,\left(\lambda_i-\lambda_j\right)\,?$$

Comment: I think that $j\in \{1,2,..,n+1\}/\{i\}$

Comment: Then, you should fix your question.